# How should I understand $\displaystyle\sum_k f(k) \approx \int dk \ f(k)$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

I am trying to understand the statement: $$\sum_{k\geq 0} f(k) \approx \int dk\  f(k).$$ When we do an integral, $dk$ is an infinitesimal and so we are roughly speaking, summing over all values of $f(k)$?

Comment: Yes, basically that's true

Comment: Yes. The limit as the partitions in the sum approach zero gives the definite integral.

Comment: Lets add in some summation/integration limits: we have $\sum_{k=0}^n f(k) \approx \int_0^n f(x){\rm d}x$ (for the case of summing over all integers take $n\to\infty$). It might be easier to see this from [a picture](http://calculus.seas.upenn.edu/uploads/Main/IntegralTestBelow.png). The integral is the area under the black curve and the sum is the area of the rectangles. This approximation can be made more precise, see e.g. [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence).

Comment: @Winther You are doing astrophysics at Oxford :) That is so so so so cool :)) Congrats. In my personal opinion, there is nothing better than doing astrophysics in this world :)))

Answer (score 5):

That's not entirely true, it *is* true for **monotone** functions, at least up to a bounded constant term found by using the LRAM and RRAM approximations, but this is usually what they mean by the $\approx$ symbol. However, take the function $f(x) = |\sin(\pi x)|$ for example, then

$$\sum_{k\in\Bbb Z}f(k) = 0\not\approx \int_{\Bbb R}f(x) \,dx =\infty$$

because the latter integral diverges, and diverges at least linearly by drawing a positive triangular wave function below the sine wave, so even

$$\sum_{k=1}^n f(x) = 0\not\approx {n\over 2}x\le \int_1^nf(x)\,dx.$$

Answer (score 2):

The statement 
$$\sum_{k\geq 0} f(k) \approx \int dk\  f(k)\tag{1}$$ 
is not a well-defined mathematical statement. The symbol $\approx$ is usually used in a heuristic argument. The left hand side of the identity, if it converges at all, is a number.  Also, the right hand side of the equality is an ambiguous notation:

- it could mean an indefinite integral of $f$;
- it could denote the Lebesgue integral over $\mathbb{R}$;
- or in a seldom used case, it means the improper Riemann integral
  $$
  \int_0^\infty f(x)\ dx
  $$
  according to an analogy of the left hand side.
- or you could even achieve [Sophomore's dream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream):

\begin{align}
\int_0^1 x^{-x}\,\mathrm{d}x &= \sum_{k=1}^\infty k^{-k}\\
\int_0^1 x^x   \,\mathrm{d}x &= \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k+1}k^{-k} = - \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-k)^{-k}.
\end{align}

---

A precise statement could be as follows (thanks to the article mentioned by Winther)

Consider an integer $N$ and a non-negative, continuous function $f$ defined on the unbounded interval $[N, \infty)$, on which it is monotone *decreasing*. Then the infinite series

$$\sum_{n=N}^\infty f(n)$$
converges to a real number if and only if the improper integral

$$\int_N^\infty f(x)\,dx$$
is finite. In other words, if the integral diverges, then the series diverges as well.

If the improper integral is finite, one has the lower and upper bounds
$$
\int_N^\infty f(x)\,dx\le\sum_{n=N}^\infty f(n)\le f(N)+\int_N^\infty f(x)\,dx\tag{2}
 $$
for the infinite series. Now, $(2)$ gives a sense of (1)